# Using Executors in very high-load environment

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I manage to write a REST API using Stripe Framework. Inside my API, I have several tasks which need to execute and combine their results. I come up with an approach, borrowed from JavaScript, which will spawn tasks into several threads and join rather than chronological implementation. Thus, I used `ExecutorService` but I found a bottleneck on the implementation when the number of requests is quite big, tasks are finished on a longer time than I expect.

My question is related to an alternate way to achieve the same purpose.

1. How can I create an Executors per request
2. How can I expand Executors' size

To demonstrate, let consider this way on Javascript

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';
let tasks = [];
tasks.push(task01);
tasks.push(task02);
Promise.all(tasks).then(results => { do_sth_here!} )
```

Bring this idea to Java, I have implemented like below

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
List<Callable<Promise>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
List<Future<Promise>> PromiseAll;

try {
    tasks.add(() -> TaskPromises(Input));
    tasks.add(() -> TaskPromise(Input));
    PromiseAll = exec.invokeAll(tasks);
    for (Future<Promise> fr : PromiseAll) {
        // do_some_thing_next
    }           
}
```

Comment: While you mention JavaScript in the question, this is not a JavaScript question. I've removed the tag so people aren't pinged incorrectly.

Comment: Maybe you should throttle your requests instead. Creating an executor per request will only lead to creating a huge amount of threads which will hurt throughput. That is also probably what is hurting here: try creating a thread pool with a max number of threads of maybe 2 x cores.

Comment: You may want to use a `ForkJoinPool`. This is an `ExecutorService` which manages `ForkJoinTask`s; those are Thread-like classes which know how to split their work and fork out to parralelize it.

Comment: In case I create a thread pool, I'm wondering how I can join some arbitrary threads. Can you give me more hints?

Comment: You don't actually join threads in an `ExecutorService`, but you can move the idea to the task they've been given: [`invokeAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-)